# Websocket Secure using Javascript client and Python server

Tags: python, php, ssl, websocket, wss

I have embarked on a learning quest about sockets, particularly websockets. I wish to use a php website as a front end, while using a regular python script (not via CGI) as my server side script. I wish to use https for my webpage and the secure version of websockets (wss) but can't seem to find anything that works. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Here is my Javascript client:

```
ws = new WebSocket('wss://192.168.2.150:8000/');
ws.onmessage = function(event){document.write("message received"); alert(event.data); ws.close();}
ws.onopen = function(){console.log("connection is established");}
ws.onerror = function(event) {
    console.error("ws fail:", event);
}
```

The webpage which this javascript is running on is being accessed by my desktop at 192.168.2.135.

The same computer that is running the apache2 server is also running my python script. This python script is hosting the websockets server. It is from Dave P (https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server) but i have modified it slightly. Here's that code:

```
import signal
import sys
import ssl
from SimpleWebSocketServer import WebSocket, SimpleWebSocketServer, SimpleSSLWebSocketServer
from optparse import OptionParser

class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):

   def handleMessage(self):
      self.sendMessage(self.data)

   def handleConnected(self):
      pass

   def handleClose(self):
      pass

clients = []


if __name__ == "__main__":

   parser = OptionParser(usage="usage: %prog [options]", version="%prog 1.0")
   parser.add_option("--host", default='192.168.2.150', type='string', action="store", dest="host", help="hostname (192.168.2.150)")
   parser.add_option("--port", default=8000, type='int', action="store", dest="port", help="port (8000)")
   parser.add_option("--example", default='echo', type='string', action="store", dest="example", help="echo, chat")
   parser.add_option("--ssl", default=1, type='int', action="store", dest="ssl", help="ssl (1: on (default), 0: off")
   parser.add_option("--cert", default='/var/www/html/mainframe/ssl/cacert.pem', type='string', action="store", dest="cert", help="cert (/var/www/html/mainframe/ssl/cacert.pem)")
   parser.add_option("--key", default='/var/www/html/mainframe/ssl/cakey.pem', type='string', action="store", dest="key", help="key (/var/www/html/mainframe/ssl/cakey.pem)")#/etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
   parser.add_option("--ver", default=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, type=int, action="store", dest="ver", help="ssl version")

   (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

   cls = SimpleEcho
   if options.example == 'chat':
      cls = SimpleChat

   if options.ssl == 1:
      server = SimpleSSLWebSocketServer(options.host, options.port, cls, options.cert, options.key, version=options.ver)
   else:
      server = SimpleWebSocketServer(options.host, options.port, cls)

   def close_sig_handler(signal, frame):
      server.close()
      sys.exit()

   signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, close_sig_handler)

   server.serveforever()
```

Using Wireshark I can see that my client and server do handshake and when the browser send a "Client Hello" the server resonds with a "Server Hello" and key. Then the client sends back its encryption key. But then the browser sends an "Encryption Alert". What does this mean? Has it got anything to do with my self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes, most likely it is a CA error. Can you try launching chrome like so from command line: chromium --user-data-dir=/tmp/whatever --ignore-certificate-errors

Comment: Hello Luv. Thanks for the quick response. You appear to be correct! I got the socket to connect and transmit data. Do you have any clue as to how I would go about creating a certificate that is not invalid? Preferably using openssl. Thank you. :)

Comment: you need to get it from a valid CA. Unfortunately, it is a problem to do that for intranet. You could navigate to https://<your server>:8000  and force your browser to accept the certificate. Then it will work. You cannot ship this code but that is a problem for another day.

Comment: Okay, I will look in to it further. Thank you very much!